# Converting and Subtracting Two Dates

Tags: t-sql, date

I'm trying to get the numeric difference between two dates.  (Ex:  11/30/2018 - 11/05/2018 = 25)

One of the dates (@EndOfMonth) represent the last day of the prior month and is being converted into a 'yyyymmdd' format

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @EndOfMonth AS VARCHAR(10)
SET @EndOfMonth = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, DATEADD(m, 1, DATEADD(MM, -1, @maxDwdate))), -1), 112))
```

The second date that I'm looking to subtract from @EndOfMonth, is a field named "DUEDATE" and it's in a 'mm/dd/yyyy' format.

Comment: The proper `DATE` data type does not have a "format", not until you convert it to a string. So, stop converting `DATE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly simple to achieve, the below example code shows how to do this (replace the DueDate variable with your DUEDATE column from your table. Basically, you use DATEDIFF to get the start of the month for DUEDATE, add one month to this date then substract one day. This will always give you the EoM date for the DUEDATE month, regardless fo the number of days in that month.

You can then simply do a DATEDIFF to work out the number of days between the two dates. SQL Server will implicitly convert **yyyymmdd** into a DATETIME value for the calculation, but if its possible, you should avoid converting the EndOfMonth variable to a string for performance reasons.

```
DECLARE @EndOfMonth VARCHAR(10),
    @DueDate DATETIME = '12/14/2018'

SELECT @EndOfMonth = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, 1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @DueDate), 0))), 112)

SELECT DATEDIFF(d, @DueDate, @EndOfMonth)
```

Comment: That seemed to be the winning ticket, THANK YOU KINDLY

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have a valid reason to convert the date to a string, and that you cannot change that logic: declare yourself a variable to store the intermediate results of the date arithmetic before you convert it to a string, then you can easily get the difference between the two dates:

```
DECLARE @eom DATE 
      = DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, DATEADD(m, 1, DATEADD(MM, -1, @maxDwdate))), -1);
DECLARE @EndOfMonth AS VARCHAR(10)
    SET @EndOfMonth = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, @eom, 112))
 SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @eom, DUTEDATE) AS DAYS
   FROM t; -- replace with actual table name.
```

Comment: A little rough but I was able to get it to work

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Which part was there a problem with?